# Are there any free bilingual books in Spanish and English?

Tags: recursos

I guess bilingual books may speed up the learning process a little bit.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is out of the scope this site. You can read in our [FAQ] what kind of questions you can ask. Questions that are not related to Spanish Language and Usage are off topic.

Answer (score 2):

I can´t think of any good site for that purpose. There are places in which you can find free books, both in English (mostly) and in Spanish (few), such as "Project Gutenberg", but they tend to be "old books", and old Spanish, as old English is sometimes not easy to understand, and they both use expressions which are obselete nowadays.

In my opinion, one of the best ways to compare equivalent sentences in both (modern) languages are bilingual DVDs: watching a movie (or part of it) in both languages. But that is not free. It can be cheap, if you rent the DVDs or you buy films which are not recent hits, but not free.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite site is the [International Children's Digital Library](http://en.childrenslibrary.org/) which also has an iOS app if you're so inclined. It essentially presents a searchable collection of scanned children's books in many different languages and skill levels.  There are many filtering criteria which makes it easy to browse.  Create a login for free to save your favorites.  The amazing thing about the entire site is that it's entirely free.